# Unable to resolve type:System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography with sql server geography data type returned in odata

Tags: jaydata

I have a table in sql server with geography type.  I use entity framework and EntitySetController to return a [Queryable] list of the entity containing the geography column.

Here is an example of the returned data:

```
{
        "d":{
            "__count":"19534",
            "results":[
               {
                   "__metadata":{
                       "id":"http://localhost:2663/odata/Airports(1)",
                       "uri":"http://localhost:2663/odata/Airports(1)",
                       "type":"AirportDB.Airport"
                   },
                   "Id":1,
                   "SiteNumber":"50009.*A",
                   "Abbrev":"ADK",
                   "Name":"Adak",
                   "Type":"AIRPORT",
                   "GeoLocation":{
                       "__metadata":{
                           "type":"System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography"
                       },
                       "WellKnownValue":{
                           "__metadata":{
                               "type":"System.Data.Spatial.DbGeographyWellKnownValue"
                           },
                           "CoordinateSystemId":4326,
                           "WellKnownText":"POINT (-176.646 51.878)",
                           "WellKnownBinary":null
                       }
                   },
                   "LocationID":"'ADK",
                   "EffectiveDate":"\/Date(1367452800000)\/",
                   "Region":"AAL",
                   "DistrictOffice":"NONE",
                   "State":"AK",
                   "StateName":"ALASKA",
                   "County":"ALEUTIAN ISLANDS",
                   "CountyState":"AK",
                   "City":"ADAK ISLAND",
                   "FacilityName":"ADAK",
                   "Ownership":"PU",
                   "Use":"PU",
                   "Owner":"STATE OF ALASKA-DOTPF-CENTRAL RGN",
                   "OwnerAddress":"P O BOX 196900",
                   "OwnerCSZ":"\"ANCHORAGE, AK 99519\"",
                   "OwnerPhone":"    907-269-0751",
                   "Manager":"VINCE TUTIAKOFF",
                   "ManagerAddress":"P O BOX 1952",
                   "ManagerCSZ":"\"ADAK, AK 99546\"",
                   "ManagerPhone":"    907-592-8026",
                   "Latitude":51.877963888888893,
                   "Longitude":-176.64603055555554,
                   "ARPLatitude":"51-52-40.6700N",
                   "ARPLatitudeS":"186760.6700N",
                   "ARPLongitude":"176-38-45.7100W",
                   "ARPLongitudeS":"635925.7100W",
                   "ARPMethod":"E",
                   "ARPElevation":18,
                   "ARPElevationMethod":"S",
                   "MagneticVariation":"07E",
                   "MagneticVariationYear":2000,
                   "TrafficPatternAltitude":0,
                   "ChartName":"W ALEUTIAN ISLS",
                   "DistanceFromCBD":0,
                   "DirectionFromCBD":"W",
                   "LandAreaCoveredByAirport":0,
                   "BoundaryARTCCID":"ZAN",
                   "BoundaryARTCCComputerID":"ZAN",
                   "BoundaryARTCCName":"ANCHORAGE",
                   "ResponsibleARTCCID":"ZAP",
                   "ResponsibleARTCCComputerID":"ZAP",
                   "ResponsibleARTCCName":"ANCHORAGE OCEANIC",
                   "TieInFSS":"N",
                   "TieInFSSID":"CDB",
                   "TieInFSSName":"COLD BAY",
                   "AirportToFSSPhoneNumber":"907-532-2466",
                   "TieInFSSTollFreeNumber":"1-800-478-7250",
                   "AlternateFSSID":"ENA",
                   "AlternateFSSName":"KENAI",
                   "AlternateFSSTollFreeNumber":"1-866-864-1737",
                   "NOTAMFacilityID":"ADK",
                   "NOTAMService":"Y",
                   "ActiviationDate":"\/Date(-654912000000)\/",
                   "AirportStatusCode":"O",
                   "CertificationTypeDate":"I A S 04/2005",
                   "FederalAgreements":"N",
                   "AirspaceDetermination":"NO OBJECTION",
                   "CustomsAirportOfEntry":"N",
                   "CustomsLandingRights":"N",
                   "MilitaryJointUse":"N",
                   "MilitaryLandingRights":"Y",
                   "InspectionMethod":"F",
                   "InspectionGroup":"F",
                   "LastInspectionDate":9202012,
                   "LastOwnerInformationDate":1081991,
                   "FuelTypes":"A1",
                   "AirframeRepair":"NONE",
                   "PowerPlantRepair":"NONE",
                   "BottledOxygenType":"NONE",
                   "BulkOxygenType":"NONE",
                   "LightingSchedule":"SEE RMK",
                   "BeaconSchedule":"SS-SR",
                   "ATCT":"N",
                   "UNICOMFrequencies":0,
                   "CTAFFrequency":122.9,
                   "SegmentedCircle":"Y",
                   "BeaconColor":"CG",
                   "NonCommercialLandingFee":"",
                   "MedicalUse":"",
                   "SingleEngineGA":0,
                   "MultiEngineGA":0,
                   "JetEngineGA":0,
                   "HelicoptersGA":0,
                   "GlidersOperational":0,
                   "MilitaryOperational":0,
                   "Ultralights":0,
                   "OperationsCommercial":212,
                   "OperationsCommuter":0,
                   "OperationsAirTaxi":0,
                   "OperationsGALocal":0,
                   "OperationsGAItin":100,
                   "OperationsMilitary":28,
                   "OperationsDate":"\/Date(1325376000000)\/",
                   "AirportPositionSource":"",
                   "AirportPositionSourceDate":"",
                   "AirportElevationSource":"",
                   "AirportElevationSourceDate":"",
                   "ContractFuelAvailable":"",
                   "TransientStorage":"HGR",
                   "OtherServices":"CARGO",
                   "WindIndicator":"Y"
               }
            ]
        }
}
```

Jaydata, in factory config mode, throws an exception: "Unable to resolve type:System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography".

What am I doing wrong?  How do I return the geography columns back to jaydata in a way it likes?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

@robesz Based on your JayStorm Paas Open Edition suggestion I created an account, created a matching schema, created a .Net console app to add some data, but it complains about an invalid format in the GeoLocation column.  How do I fix that? Additionally, it first complained about needing odata v3 when I executed line SaveChanges(), but the import process hardcodes V2, so I hand edited the generated client side stub (not ideal) - how would I fix that?  And also, is there no easier way to import data in to JayStorm tables?  And finally, where can I find pricing about more than 1 million records?

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var db = new AirportDB.mydatabaseService(new Uri("https://open.jaystack.net/c72e6c4b-27ba-49bb-9321-e167ed03d00b/6494690e-1d5f-418d-adca-0ac515b7b742/api/mydatabase/"));

            var airport = new Airport.Airport();
            airport.Abbrev = "Foo";
            airport.Name = "Bar";

            airport.GeoLocation = GeographyPoint.Create(51.8779638888889, -176.646030555556);
            db.AddToAirport(airport);

            db.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Geo types we use GeoJSON. You can do the following:
Let's suppose you have an EntitySet with the following structure:

```
 point:
    id: int,
    point: $data.GeographyPoint
```

when you retrieve your points use map (projection):

```
 context.points.map(function(p) { return { id: id, point: { lat: Latitude, lng: Longitude } }, {}, "default")
```

please let us know if it works for you or not

Comment: My issue is that using the add service wizard and using c# is the richest and easiest way for me to insert/update/delete data in mass quantities from either files or sql server tables.  However once I include a GeoLocation type in my table the "add service" generated c# can no longer do anything - even selects - because of the conflict of the c# GeoLocation type with the server side type.  Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Your service endpoint must expose the Geo points in [OData standard format](http://www.odata.org/2011/05/geospatial-data-support-in-odata/) - 
Example responses can be found by inspecting J[ayData Geo examples](http://jaydata.org/examples/?tags=Geo).

You have a couple of options to do this:
1. ASP.NET WebAPI with WebAPI OData extension

**Model:**

```
public class Place
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public System.Spatial.GeographyPoint Location { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions=AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
public IQueryable<Place> Get()
{
  data = new List<Place>();
  data.Add(new Place() { Id = 0, Name = "Place1", Description = "Desc", Location = GeographyPoint.Create(-1.56, 29.76) });
  data.Add(new Place() { Id = 1, Name = "Place1", Description = "Desc", Location = GeographyPoint.Create(-2.56, 19.76) });

  return data.AsQueryable();
}
```

As far as I know Entity Framework has some troubles with this type, but probably this has improved.

1. You can use the [odata-server](http://jaydata.org/blog/jaydata-server) npm module on nodejs, this is the server-side JayData with useful helpers. You can expose the points, geo.distance() and geo.intersects() will work only with JayData MongoDB Provider Pro.
2. You can save your point to [JayStorm PaaS Open Edition](http://jaystack.com/blog/jaystorm-open%E2%80%93starting-point) for free and build your own schema by point-and-clicks - adding a Geography Point field.

Comment: Can you pleae help me understand why column filters are not working? http://jsfiddle.net/t316/YZpcZ/5/   And also is there a way to have auto-increment long int primary keys instead of the built in object type?

Comment: And to my surprise the MVVM version seems work exactly the same way: http://jsfiddle.net/t316/4n62B/7/  Meaning it works nicely (but has the filter bug)...  So, using the MVVM approach in durandal is probably running in to some weird promise issues...

Comment: it's a bug in jaystorm, we have the fix, we'll update jaystorm within days